# StatsModel quantile regression ValueError

Tags: python, numpy, regression, statsmodels, quantile

I got an error after running quantile regression in Python StatsModel module.  The error is following:

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-221-3547de1b5e0d> in <module>()
 16 model = smf.quantreg(fit_formula, train)
 17
---> 18 fitted_model = model.fit(0.2)
 19
 20 #fitted_model.predict(test)

 in fit(self, q, vcov, kernel, bandwidth, max_iter, p_tol, **kwargs)
177             resid = np.abs(resid)
178             xstar = exog / resid[:, np.newaxis]
--> 179             diff = np.max(np.abs(beta - beta0))
180             history['params'].append(beta)
181             history['mse'].append(np.mean(resid*resid))

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (178,) (176,)
```

I was thinking it was possibly caused by constant features, so I removed those, but I still got the same error.  I am wondering what is the cause.  My code is following:

```
quantiles = np.arange(.05, .99, .1)

cols = train.columns.tolist()[1:-2]
fit_formula = ''
for c in cols:
    fit_formula =  fit_formula + ' + ' + c
fit_formula = 'revenue ~ ' + train.columns.tolist()[0] + fit_formula

model = smf.quantreg(fit_formula, train)

fitted_model = model.fit(0.2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your design matrix is singular, i.e. this does not hold for your data:

`np.linalg.matrix_rank(model.exog) == model.exog.shape[1]`

Guessing from looking at the code: The parameter, beta, is initialized for the iteration loop with

```
exog_rank = np_matrix_rank(self.exog)
beta = np.ones(exog_rank)
```

which has different lengtht than the beta from the auxiliary weighted least squares regression, and the convergence check fails. The iteratively reweighted step used a generalized inverse, pinv, which does not raise an exception because of the singular design matrix.

Based on your traceback, (178,) (176,), you would still have two collinear columns that need to be dropped.

(That's a bug: Either it should raise a proper exception for the singular case, or handle it with pinv throughout.)

Comment: thanks, this totally answered my question.  After removing correlated features with a less strict cut-off, I was able to run it through.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Bug issue to track when this behavior will change is https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/3746